# Haskell 'count occurrences' function

Tags: haskell

I implemented a `count` function in Haskell and I am wondering will this behave badly on large lists :

```
count   :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Int
count x =  length . filter (==x)
```

I believe the `length` function runs in linear time, is this correct?

Edit: Refactor suggested by @Higemaru

Comment: If you are really paranoid, you can also always do the equivalent of a single loop: `count needle haystack = foldl' (\acc elem -> if elem == needle then acc+1 else acc) 0 haystack`.

Comment: You can't really count n items any faster than O(n), so I'm not sure what your worry is.

Comment: @augustss - my worry was if I was doing a double pass over a list.

Comment: @decentral1se Thanks to laziness it will behave more like a single pass.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Length runs in linear time to the size of the list, yes.

Normally, you would be worried that your code had to take two passes through the list: first one to filter and then one to count the length of the resulting list. However, I believe this does not happen here because filter is not strict on the structure of the list. Instead, the length function forces the elements of the filtered list as it goes along, doing the actual count in one pass.

Comment: I don’t think it’s laziness, but stream fusion. If you look at the output of `-ddump-simpl`, at `-O0` it’s two separate calls and at `-O2` it’s a single worker.

Comment: Hmm,wouldn't it still be one pass even *without* stream fusion, just because of the way filter is lazy? Maybe I'm just misunderstanding how it would be evaluated.

Comment: Yes, it's a single pass even without fusion.  The fusion only helps to get rid of the memory allocation in that pass.

Answer (score 9):

I think you can make it slightly shorter

```
count :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Int
count x = length . filter (x==)
```

(I would have written a (lowly) comment if I could)

Comment: (length .) . filter . (==) ;) Ha, just kidding.

Comment: @Jepcats I can't get it to work in ghci when interactively typing it in. With the right type signature (and loaded from a file on disk) it works but isn't the following odd?

`Prelude> :t (length .) . filter . (==)`
`(length .) . filter . (==) :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Int`
`Prelude> let count = (length .) . filter . (==)`
`Prelude> :t count`
`count :: () -> [()] -> Int`

(sorry, can't seem to get formatting right)

Comment: That is strange. I don't see the same thing in my GHCI. I can type the following commands: `λ> :t (length .) . filter . (==)` which outputs 
`(length .) . filter . (==) :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Int` and also `λ> let count = (length .) . filter . (==)` followed by `λ> :t count` which outputs `count :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Int`, as expected. Worth noting is that if I put a pointfree definition of count in a .hs file it fails to compile without a type signature.

Comment: @Jepcats sorry for getting back to you after such a long time. I get `count :: () -> [()] -> Int`
where you get `count :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Int`. My GHCi version seems to be 7.6.3. Anyway, thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

That really depends on the list.  For a normal, lazily evaluated list of `Int`s on my computer, I see this function running in about 2 seconds for 10^9 elements, 0.2 seconds for 10^8, and 0.3 seconds for 10^7, so it appears to run in linear time.  You can check this yourself by passing the flags `+RTS -s -RTS` to your executable when running it from the command line.

I also tried running it with more cores, but it doesn't seem to do anything but increase the memory usage a bit.

An added bonus of the lazy computation is that you only make a single pass over the list.  `filter` and `length` get turned into a single loop by the compiler (with optimizations turned on), so you save memory and efficiency.

Comment: "That really depends on the list" -- example?  What's a list that isn't "normal, lazily evaluated"?  Even if you mean "a previously evaluated list" then this should still have linear runtime.  (Graph reduction does *less* work than applicative-order reduction -- the trouble is usually space leaks.)  As for running with more cores, Haskell doesn't automagically parallelize sequential single-threaded code.  List traversal takes linear time anyway, so you could expect (at most) a constant factor.  Finally, laziness is still a win (you don't force the intermediate list as in a strict language) ...

Comment: regardless of whether or not you turn on optimizations.  Sorry for sounding critical -- your post is just a little bit vague.  Let's not make Haskell performance a darker art than it has to be :)  On the other hand, your empirical approach is also quite necessary ...

Comment: @Fixnum Well, instead of using GHC's built-in list type, you could use vectors (boxed and unboxed), pre-sorted lists, and various other "list-like" data structures.  I also know that GHC (not Haskell, since we're being technical) can't parallelize everything, but I've written algorithms that perform wildly differently with `-threaded` and `+RTS -N -RTS`, even when there isn't any explicit parallelism.  Finally, I added the comment about having optimizations turned on because I was unsure of all the optimizations GHC might do compared to having them turned off.  Sorry for the vagueness.